# Faster way to import thousands of records from a single txt file into database MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, import, phpmyadmin

I have like 50 txt files each with around 8 columns and 80,000 records. I have written a script in Matlab that reads all the files one by one and then puts it into MySQL using a single INSERT statement for each file. However doing so is taking a huge amount of time(even for a single file!). I have also tried using PHPmyAdmin which says the file is too big to upload (around 8 MB). So please suggest a workaround and what is the ideal way to usually import large txt files. Also how much time should it normally take to import 1 single such file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LOAD DATA INFILE` syntax.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Comment: yeah, the LOAD DATA seems to work pretty quick. wonder why single insert for multiple records takes so much time!!

Answer (score 2):

All you need is in this manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-speed.html

Answer (score 1):

Try [mysqlimport](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html)

Also table type of myisam will import faster, depends on if you need transactional support (innodb).

Comment: start transaction before inserting and InnoDB catches up with MyISAM (don't forget to commit after ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Use multible INSERTS. It isn't that expensive, since you still connect to mysql only once. You can then use a loop to update your values ( -> your sql) and execute (i think it's "fetch" for mathlab) the query.

(see http://spx.arizona.edu/Projects/Database/Accessing%20mySQL%20through%20Matlab.pdf for example)